# ¿Como cambiar configuración del panel de control, temas, accesibilidad, pantalla etc con un batch?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, windows10, configuración

Buenas.
Me gustaría saber como podría en caso de que fuese posible, cambiar la configuración como un tema de windows, resolución, ppp, mouse y cualquier cosa que pueda cambiar desde el panel de control en Windows 10 o Windows 7 usando un batch.
¿Es posible o no merece la pena?

Mi idea era automatizar varios cambios, que sé que por ejemplo en Windows 7 se pueden guardar temas y configuraciones pero no estoy seguro de como hacer varios procedimientos en un batch.

Tampoco estoy seguro de si al guardar la configuración de un tema se guardará tambien la resolución, los ppp y otras configuraciónes como puedan ser de accesibilidad de forma que si activo otro tema y vuelvo a cambiar al tema personalizado que habia guardado restableceré esos cambios.

He buscado y no he enocntrado nada sobre batch así que intuyo que esto de poder hacerse no será la mejor manera, pero hay codigo para hacer esto que digo?

Hay configuraciones que al guardar un tema puede que se queden guardados, pero si yo exporto el tema y lo llevo a otro PC algunos de esas configuraciones podrían no haberse guardado porque irían aparte.

Mi idea era que si tengo que trasladar algunas configuraciones poder ejecutar un batch y hacer los cambios comodamente ejecutando ese archivo batch.

Espero que la pregunta no resulte abierta. Yo creo que estoy preguntando algo bastante concreto:

Ajustar mediante batch lo siguiente:

- Resolución
- ppp o (dpi?)
- Tema visual de cualquier tipo: Normal, Architectura, Personajes, los de alto contraste de la accesibilidad
- Activar o cambiar configuraciones del apartado de accesibilidad (como teclado en pantalla, lector de pantalla etc.
- Cambiar mouse, velocidad, opciones extras del mouse etc...
- Cambiar sonidos

En resumen cosas del estilo que se cambiarian desde el menu de personalizar o desde el panel de control.
Espero que se haya entendido la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) para automatizar el proceso de cambio de resolución. En tu caso podrías realizar un batch que ejecutara **`nircmd.exe setdisplay [anchura][altura][Número_de_colores]`**

Para las demás tareas que necesitas se requiere de un poco más que un simple comando batch. Por ejemplo, para realizar un cambio en el comportamiento del mouse es necesario acceder al registro, pero aún así hay características que no pueden y no deben ser cambiadas desde un command prompt.

Otra opción sería buscar cada entrada en el registro de las configuraciones que deseas 'exportar' y concatenarlas para realizar una sola entrada en el equipo de destino.

Por ejemplo,

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel
```

Contiene el registro de la mayoría de configuraciones en el Panel de control. Lo que dificulta la tarea es que una entrada incorrecta en el registro del equipo de destino generaría conflictos que sólo podrían ser solucionados con una **reinstalación de Windows**.

Sin embargo, haciendo un poco de investigación, encontré una herramienta que quizás te pueda servir para gran parte del propósito que tienes en mente. [ClassicShell](http://www.classicshell.net/) Es un programa que personaliza las características de Windows y permite exportarlas de una manera fácil y rápida.